# Por qué los decoradores usan funciones anidadas?

Tags: python-3.x, decoradores

Si el decorador es una función que agrega funcionalidades a otra función, por que usa una función anidada para ello pudiendo definir dichas funcionalidades o acciones en su ámbito local y simplemente retornarse a si misma?

es decir:

```
def monitorizar(funcion):
       print("")
       funcion()
       print("")
       return monitorizar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es así como funciona.

El decorador es una función `A` que recibe como parámetro otra función `B` y retorna como resultado otra función `C`.

```
def A(B):
   # Definir quizas C
   # Usar quizás B
   return C
```

Una vez definido el decorador (la función `A`), se puede usar con esta sintaxis:

```
@A
def F():
   ...
```

que no es más que *azúcar sintáctico* para esto otro, que es equivalente:

```
auxiliar = A(F)
F = auxiliar
```

Es decir, se ejecuta la función decorador `A()` pasándole en su parámetro `B` el argumento `F`. El decorador retornará otra función `C`, y finalmente el valor de `F` se sustituye por el valor de `C`, de modo que en lo sucesivo, cada vez que invoques `F()`, en realidad se estará llamando `C`.

Lo que tú propones es que `A` y `C` sean lo mismo, por lo que si lo hiciéramos así, al llamar a F en lo sucesivo, estaríamos llamando a `A`, el decorador. Esto no funcionará como esperas.

En esencia propones lo siguiente:

```
def A(B):
   print("Se ejecuta el decorador")
   B() # Delegamos en la función original
   print("El decorador ha terminado")
   return A
```

Pero ahora, al usarlo como siempre:

```
@A
def F():
   print("Se ejecuta la función original")
```

empezarían a pasar cosas raras. De entrada este código hemos dicho que equivale a este otro:

```
auxiliar = A(F)
F = auxiliar
```

por tanto en este punto se ejecutará el decorador. Esto causará el texto "Se ejecuta el decorador", etc. *pero también causará la ejecución de B, que es F*, por lo que también saldrá "Se ejecuta la función original". Esto ya está mal, pues al decorar una función F no queremos que F se ejecute todavía.

Pero **además** fallará más adelante al tratar de ejecutar `F()`, ya que estaríamos en realidad ejecutando `A()`, que es el decorador y que necesita como parámetro una función que no le estamos pasando. Ni le podemos pasar, ya que en general los parámetros que requerirá `F()` son distintos de los que requiere el decorador `A()`. Encontraremos:

```
F()
TypeError: A() missing 1 required positional argument: 'B'
```

En cambio la forma buena de hacerlo no causa estos problemas:

```
def A(B):
  print("Se ejecuta el decorador")
  def C():
    print("Se ejecuta la función decorada")
    B()
    print("La función decorada ha terminado")
  print("El decorador ha terminado")
  return C
```

Ahora, al ejecutar lo siguiente:

```
@A
def F():
  print("Se ejecuta la función original")
```

veremos en pantalla:

```
Se ejecuta el decorador
El decorador ha terminado
```

lo que es correcto, pues se ha ejecutado `A(F)`, pero es no ha causado que se ejecute la función interna `C`, (solo se ha definido y se ha retornado como valor a asignarle a `F`). Por tanto no se ha ejecutado `F` aún.

Cuando más tarde la ejecutemos:

```
F()
```

en realidad se estará ejecutando la función `C()`, retornada por el decorador. Efectivamente en este punto veremos:

```
Se ejecuta la función decorada
Se ejecuta la función original
La función decorada ha terminado
```